# Postgres, find the min value of array column and get its position

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Let us assume the following table: test

```
ids | l_ids      |  distance
-----------------+-----------
 53 | {150,40}   | {1.235, 2.265}
 22 | {20,520}   | {0.158, 0.568}
```

The positions of the two arrays (l_ids, distance) are dependent, meaning that
150 corresponds to 1.235,
40  corresponds to 2.265 and so on.

I want to get the min distance and the respective l_id. Therefore the result should be like this:

```
   ids | l_ids      |  distance
   ----------------+-----------
    53 |  150       |  1.235
    22 |   20       |  0.158
```

By running this:

```
select l_ids, min(dist) as min_distance 
from test, unnest(test.distance) dist
group by 1;
```

the result is:

```
     l_ids      |  dist
    ------------+-----------
     {150,40}   |  1.235
     {20,520}   |  0.158
```

I want to get the position of the minimum value in the array of distance in order to get the respective id from the array of l_ids.

Any guideline? Thank you in advance

Comment: in `distance` array, values are unique? or may be `{1.235, 1.235, 2.265}` also happens?

Comment: The length of the arrays may be greater than 2, but always equal to each other.

Comment: can you have in `l_ids` for example: `{150, 70, 40} ` and in `distance` these values:  `{1.235, 1.235, 2.265}` (`1.235` repeates)

Comment: Which PostgreSQL version do you use?

Comment: psql (9.5.4) version

Comment: Please check the edits in my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ctid) l_ids, distance
FROM (SELECT ctid,
             unnest(l_ids) AS l_ids,
             unnest(distance) AS distance
      FROM test
     ) q
ORDER BY ctid, distance;

 l_ids | distance
-------+----------
   150 |    1.235
    20 |    0.158
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works. Check please my edit in the question.

Comment: Use `ids` instead of `ctid`.

Answer (score 1):

If ids are unique identiter, and you don't have repeated values in `distance` array, this should work:

```
SELECT a.* from  
(SELECT ids, UNNEST(l_ids) AS l_ids, UNNEST (distance) AS distance  FROM test) a
INNER JOIN (SELECT ids, MIN(distance) as mind FROM (
        SELECT ids,  UNNEST (distance) AS distance  FROM test 
    ) t
GROUP BY ids ) t
ON
a.ids = t.ids and a.distance = t.mind
```

Comment: Thanks, it s really closed to the solution. However it returns 12 rows more. I checked for duplicates. The ids are unique and there is no repeated value in distance.

Comment: As I said it s really closed. The query returns 10 duplicates of ids. However each duplicate has the same min distance, which is not critical for my further work. Thanks again for the assistance

Comment: So, its seems that you have duplicates in distance array, this causes more rows in result. glad if this was helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

From 9.4, you can use [`UNNEST()`'s special `ROWS FROM()`-like syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS):

```
select   distinct on (ids) ids, l_id, dist min_distance
from     test, unnest(l_ids, test.distance) d(l_id, dist)
order by ids, dist
```

Otherwise, this is typical [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) query.

Comment: + for conciseness.